# Incomplete mapping on nested lists / circular dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I'm using Automapper to map my EF-Entities to ViewModel classes.

This is my Model:

```
public class Audit: Model
{ 
    ...
    public ICollection<Answer> AuditResults { get; set; }
    public AuditCatalog AuditCatalog { get; set; }
}

public class AuditCatalog : Model
{
    ...
    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Audit> Audits { get; set; }
}

public class Question : Model
{
    ...
    public ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AuditCatalog> AuditCatalogs { get; set; }
}

public class Answer: Model
{
    ...

    public ICollection<Question> Questions  { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Audit> ResultInAudits { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AuditCatalog> AuditCatalogs { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel looks exactly the same (except additional or not needed stuff). You also might think: "OMG! That model have useless and far to many "many-to-many" references!". In fact I track changes on `Question`s and `Answer`s and logically delete entries, so let's just say i need all that.

**The Problem:**

After mapping an `Audit` of the EF-Entities (which a completely filled) some lists of the ViewModel contain null entries.

In detail:

- `Audit.AuditResults` OK
- `Audit.AuditCatalog.Questions` OK
- `Audit.AuditCatalog.Answers` 6 entries, 4 of them `null`

I think there is a problem with the circular references of the many-to-many relationships. I first thought after mapping the entries of `AuditResults` automapper is done with `Answer`s and just fills in `Audit.AuditCatalog.Answers` the already know objects, but only 1 entry (of the 2 entries that are not null) is already in `AuditResults`.

**The Workaround**

In the configuration I ignored the first list of `Answer`s.

```
CreateMap<Audit, AuditVM>()
    .ForMember(a => a.AuditResults, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Map...

```
var auditVM = mapper.Map<AuditVM>(audit);
```

...and then map the results

```
auditVM.AuditResults = mapper.Map<List<Answer>, 
    List<AnswerVM>>audit.AuditResults.ToList());
```

**The Question**

I either need to know if i'm doing it wrong or understand the limitations of automapper to avoid similar situations. I don't get behind it. Also searching the internet don't brings me on the problem.

I also think about flatten my ViewModels, but that adds more complexity to the mappings, etc.